# Selecionar dados distintos de duas tabelas excluindo os repetidos

Tags: sql

Como eu poderia selecionar em duas tabelas trazendo os dados da coluna **SKU** de ambas tabelas mesmo que os dados de uma tabela não exista na outra tabela, também preciso excluir os dados repetidos.

Estes sãos os dados da tabela **item_divergencia** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estes são os dados da tabela **item_inventarios** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o resultado esperado;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar o SQL abaixo mais minha query ficou muito lenta para consulta com muitos itens;

```
SELECT (IVT.sku) as SKU
        FROM item_divergencia as IDV
        INNER JOIN item_inventarios as IVT on (IDV.id_inventario = IVT.id_inventario)
        WHERE IDV.id_inventario='252'
      UNION
        SELECT (IDV.sku) as SKU
        FROM item_divergencia as IDV
        INNER JOIN item_inventarios as IVT on (IDV.id_inventario = IVT.id_inventario)
        WHERE IDV.id_inventario='252'
        ORDER BY SKU
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com a seguinte query:

Não havia necessidade de criar um relacionamento entre as duas tabelas.
selecionei as duas tabelas individualmente e depois usei **UNION** para juntar os dados excluindo os repetidos.

Dessa forma ficou muito rápido trazer os resultados.

```
SELECT (IVT.sku) as SKU FROM item_inventarios as IVT WHERE IVT.id_inventario='252' GROUP by SKU
UNION
SELECT (IDV.sku) as SKU FROM item_divergencia as IDV WHERE IDV.id_inventario='252' GROUP by SKU
ORDER BY SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

Para dados repetidos, já é o conceito do **GROUP BY** , aqui tem explicação e ótimos exemplos:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

em sua SQL, para agrupar tudo pelo SKU, é só usar

```
GROUP BY SKU
```

ao final.

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!

Comment: Perfeita explicação. Porem usando LEFT JOIN não traria o resultado desejado porque nas duas tabelas tenho linhas da coluna SKU que existe em uma e não existe e vise e versa.

Comment: Obrigado, vi que o Group By foi útil! Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Foi sim .. Ajudou muito. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, se for possível dar o thumbs up

Comment: Editei para deixar apenas o GROUP BY, o que realmente foi útil. Abs